# How to change just the options style in Cakephp3 input type

Tags: html, css, cakephp-3.0

I have a dropdown that displays the default color when hovered by the cursor.

```
echo $this->Form->input('filter_company', array(
    'label' => ' ', 'type' => 'select',
    'class'=>'drop', 
    'style'=>'padding-left: 40px;', 
    'options' => $company, 
    'empty' => 'Empresa', 
    'id' => 'filto1', 
    'onChange'=>'document.getElementById("filto1").submit();'
));?>
```

I think a solution would be creating an array for 'options', like this:

```
 echo $this->Form->input('filter_company', array(
     'label' => ' ', 
     'type' => 'select',
     'class'=>'drop', 
     'style'=>'padding-left: 40px;', 
     'options' => ['SOMETHING' => $company, 'class'=>'class_name'],
     'empty' => 'Empresa', 
     'id' => 'filto1', 
     'onChange'=>'document.getElementById("filto1").submit();'
));?>
```

My problem is knowing what to put in "SOMETHING" place. Someone knows the proper structure od these 'options' array, or some other way to change the options:hover style ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to set different attributes for each option

so according to the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers) you have to create an array like this

```
 'options' =>  [ 
    [ 'text' => 'Description 1', 'value' => 'value 1', 'class' => 'class_name' ],
    [ 'text' => 'Description 2', 'value' => 'value 2', 'class' => 'another_name' ],
    [ 'text' => 'Description 3', 'value' => 'value 3', 'class' => 'a_third_class' ]
     ],
```

Comment: I just don't know if this works using my variable $company.

Comment: you have to modify your $company array in order to obtain an array similar to the one in my example